# Browser-style swipe to navigate in all apps

Tags: macos, trackpad, gesture

Is it possible use a swipe gesture to navigate forwards and backwards in apps that do not natively support that gesture?

Comment: This seems to ask multiple questions at once, the site works better with one question per post. Also, what does "back" mean in other applications (e.g. Pages, Numbers, Mail)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Each application needs to define what forward and back are and then enable the gesture recognizer to map those commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate a keyboard shortcut pressing on a swipe gesture using apps like [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai/) but you will have to specify *Swipe* to *Keyboard Shortcut* mapping for every app.